# What is said to check on a planned date?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

When you have preplanned a date for something with a friend or a group of people and you want to ask if they are still committed to it and it's sort of a reminder
 Are on date? That doesn't seem right. Plus I'm unsure if date is good enough to be used since its usually used in romantic situations.

So if I planned to go witha ccouple of friends for a barbecue on Saturday, maybe I'd ask them on a Friday if they're on date/still fixed on it and up for it?
What is said?

> 1: Are you on our planned date for Saturday.
>   2: Yeah I am.

Answer (score 4):

You've almost got it.

Your sentence is incorrect:

> Are you on our planned date for Saturday?

This is better:

> > Are you on **for** our planned date for Saturday?

This is best:

> > Are **we** **still** on **for** our planned date **on** Saturday?

Here is the shorter version:

> > Are **we** **still** on **for** Saturday?

The definition of the expression, *be on for something,* according to [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-on-for-something):

> To want to do something.
>
> e.g., *Are you still on for a trip to the coast on Thursday?*

### Edit:

This is in response to the comment by the OP asking, *"Is it okay to use [date] generally? Like isn't date used as a romantic date? Or is okay to be used even in these cases?"*

Yes, it is okay. The noun, *date,* has more than one [meaning](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/date):

> 1. The day of the month or year as specified by a number.
>
>    1.1 A particular day or year when a given event occurred or will occur.
>
>    1.2 (dates) The years of a person’s birth and death or of the beginning and end of a period or event.
>
>    1.3 The period of time to which an artifact or structure belongs.
> 2. A social or romantic appointment or engagement.
>
>    2.1 A person with whom one has a social or romantic engagement.
>
>    2.2 A musical or theatrical engagement or performance, especially as part of a tour.

Comment: Is it okay to use it generally.

Comment: I do not understand your question, "Is it okay to use it generally?" Please explain what you mean by "it" and what you mean by "generally."

Comment: Like isn't date used as a romantic date. Or is it okay to be used even in these cases.

Comment: 'Date' does tend to be used for a romantic meeting, though it doesn't have to be. That is why Kyle's last suggestion, without 'date', is the best.